# MongoDB not able to save data through node.js from url http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/.json

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, request

I was trying to save data from reddit into my collection but the following error is keep coming

> **MongoError: error parsing element 0 of field documents :: caused by :: wrong type for '0' field, expected object, found 0: "stories"**

Now I am stuck in this please help

Here is my code please let me know what I am missing.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    request = require('request');
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/course', function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        request('http://reddit.com/r/technology/.json', function (err, response, body) {
            if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(body);
                var stories = obj.data.children.map(function (story) {
                    return story.data;
                });
                console.dir(stories);
                db.collection('reddit').insert('stories', function (err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.dir(data);
                    db.close();
                });
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: pass `stories` as variable, not as a `string` - insert API expects first arguments as a document/array

also you can do like this.. `db.reddit.insert(stories,function(err, data){...})`

[you can look at the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/)

Comment: if (err) throw err;
                                       ^
MongoError: driver is incompatible with this server version

This error is coming now .. what might be the reason ?

Comment: update your mongodb driver